# Is it possible to test if JS and CSS files are being loaded on a mobile phone?

Tags: optimization, responsive-design

I've got a responsive website that looks for the HTTP_USER_AGENT using PHP and then determines which JS files to load. When checking Firefox I can use Firebug/Page speed etc to check what's being loaded and so on, but on my iPhone I have no such tools. Is it possible to test this using some online or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it with alert() or Enable Safari debug Tools in the iPhone Setting for a console!

Comment: alert() = wonderful :)
Would be sweet though if there's an online tool for more extensive testing, where HTTP_USER_AGENT would think it's a mobile for example.